# All together vs altogether for results

Tags: word-usage

In editing science papers, I routinely come across the phrase "Altogether, these results suggest that..." I have changed it to "All together" because it seems to me that the phrase is referring to considering all of the results together. But I have seen "Altogether" so many times that I decided to look it up again, and now I am unsure. Perhaps the meaning is "All in all, these results suggest that..."

The examples I have seen in Garner's and Grammar Girl don't really match this situation. For example, "Altogether, I have too many socks" vs "My socks are all together in my dresser."

I am still leaning toward "All together" because it is modifying "these results" whereas in the example of "altogether" above, it is modifying "I have".

Or perhaps because it is ambiguous, I should leave it as is?

Comment: Yes, the sense of 'altogether' is 'all in all' or 'considered as a whole'. 'All together' would not be used to begin a sentence.

Comment: "All together", said the singing tutor to the class, "and put your hearts into it!"

Comment: All together or separately are alternative ways of considering a group of things or people.

Answer (score 1):

*Altogether* would be more correct in your context. You're saying that [as a whole/all in all/in total/etc.], the stated results suggest something. Altogether is therefore serving as an adverb to "suggest." [This article by Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/altogether-vs-all-together/) provides a good delineation of the two. Also see the following dictionary definitions for *altogether*: [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=altogether), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altogether), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/altogether#dataset-cald4).

The separated term, *All together*, denotes more of a grouping of discrete items than a conglomerate set of things. Some examples: "We were all together in the same place for the first time since 1995"; "After I raked the leaves all together, a strong gust of wind reversed my progress."

Comment: Thanks, the grouping vs conglomerate is useful. So is "Together, these results suggest..." correct?

Comment: That would sound odd to me because the _together_ seems a bit ambiguous standing on its own. I would want to add a clear verb before it, such as "Taken together, these results..." or, as the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=together) uses in its fourth definition for _together_, "Regarded collectively; in total: She is worth more than all of us together;  _Considered_ together, the proposals made little sense." (emphasis mine). I think **Altogether** is the most precise word for this context.